# Div not creating a block and not priventing from inside things go inside of him

Tags: html, css

For some reason my code doesn't give the highest `div` its own area and all of the other parts of the website are overlapping into the first div, what did I do wrong?

[Website](https://codepen.io/aviv240/full/QQzpdv/)

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="background-body">
    <div class="row div-border container4" style="background-color:dimgrey;">
    <div class="col-md-9 ">
    <h1 class="title" style="font-size:40px;">Computer science student ,trying    to learn Front-End develpoing and expand my knowledge on all relative subject to  computers,mostly interested in    coding<br>-----------------------------------------------------<br>C -- C++ -- Front-End Beginner  </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 center">
    <img style="border-radius:50%; width:85%; " alt="My Picture" src="https://thumb.ibb.co/min1tH/17127255_1810602309157311_608558868267532288_a.jpg" >
    </div>
    </div>


  
    <h2 style="text-align:center;"><u>My Finished Projects</u>:</h2>
```

well i just made the div with a static height for now until i can find a better solution

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

You opened 3 times div than you close 1 time and open another one and close 2 again, I think just forgot to close one div

so add another `</div>`

Comment: i did close it its jut near the footer checked it several times

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, your `div.container4` class has a fixed height:

```
div.container4 {
    height: 10em;
}
```

If you remove it, the container divs grow with the content.

Comment: it did worked it out but now its a little off as you can see in the link, btw it was working fine before have no idea what happend to make it like that

Comment: It seems ok to me now; what do you think needs fixing?

Comment: well nothing much haha its all been pretty worked out thank you :)